# Bitbake does not populate so symlinks to shared libaries

Tags: yocto, recipe, bitbake, qtgstreamer

In my Yocto layer I have such bitbake recipe for Qt Gstreamer libraries:

```
SUMMARY = "QtGStreamer libraries for Qt5"
DESCRIPTION = "QtGStreamer is a set of libraries and plugins providing C++ bindings for GStreamer with a Qt-style API plus some helper classes for integrating GStreamer better in Qt applications."
SECTION = "multimedia"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=2d5025d4aa3495befef8f17206a5b0a1"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "fd794045a828c184acc1794b08a463fd"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "9f3b492b74cad9be918e4c4db96df48dab9c012f2ae5667f438b64a4d92e8fd4"

SRC_URI = "http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/qt-gstreamer/${PN}-${PV}.tar.xz"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libgstpbutils-1.0 \
                gstreamer1.0 \
                qtdeclarative \
                glib-2.0 \
                libgstvideo-1.0 \
                libgstapp-1.0 \
                libgstaudio-1.0 \
                qtbase \
"

inherit cmake_qt5

export EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DQT_VERSION=5 \
                        -DHW_PLATFORM=imx6 \
                        -DOE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINS=${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}/usr/bin/qt5/ \
                        -DUSE_QT_PLUGIN_DIR=OFF \
                        -DCMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH=YES \
                        -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=YES \
                        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/" \
"

FILES_${PN} += "\
    ${libdir}/gstreamer-1.0/* \
"

INSANE_SKIP_qt-gstreamer = "installed-vs-shipped"

EXTRA_OECONF += "--disable-rpath"
```

As a result of this recipe in temporary build directory I have 3 files for each shared library created- one actual library and two symlinks like so:

```
libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so -> libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.0
libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.0 -> libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.1.2.0
libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.1.2.0
```

Now I wonder why in package ${PN} I have files `libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.0` and `libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so.1.2.0` but no `libQt5GStreamer-1.0.so` ?

On the other hand I have this file included in package `${PN}-dev`.

I tried to copy this file to package ${PN} by using `FILES_${PN}` but then I get QA error that I cannot have so symlinks in non-dev package.

My Qt application to play video depends on these *.so files so I need to have them on my target rootfs.

How to add those file to the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Qt application to play video depends on these *.so

This is probably the problem you should be solving: the .so should not be needed by the application at runtime. The way Yocto installs libraries and symlinks is quite standard: You will find this same division in Ubuntu and other distros.

You can silence the QA warning with `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"` but that won't change the fact that the bug is probably in the application.

Alternatively you could of course make your application depend on the -dev package.

Comment: Thank you. For now I added INSANE_SKIP_${PN} but I will rework the application building process.

Comment: Needing a .so is not always wrong, nor is it only for development.  Java JNI only looks for .so and does not use the library loading system.  So if the link to the .so is not there, the Java application will fail to find the library. Thanks BTW, for the QA disable line.  I needed this too.

Comment: There are exceptions, that is true.